# React Application: Saving Code to Database and Generating Widgets Issue

Tags: reactjs, database, axios, widget, sandbox

**Description**

I'm working on a React application that features an in-browser code editor using Ace Editor. Users can write code in this editor, and upon clicking the "Save" button, the code is successfully saved to a database via an Axios POST request.

However, my challenge arises when attempting to generate widgets from this saved code. I want to retrieve the saved code from the database, process it (possibly using **`eval()`**, a virtual machine, or other transpilation methods), and generate widgets that users can interact with using drag-and-drop functionality.

I'm seeking guidance on how to approach the widget generation process or identify potential issues in my implementation. Any insights or suggestions would be greatly appreciated.

**Environment**:

- React
- Ace Editor
- Axios
- Sanpack

**Code**

```
import React from "react";
import { CustomAceEditor } from "./CustomAceEditor";
import { SandpackProvider, SandpackPreview, SandpackFileExplorer } from "@codesandbox/sandpack-react";

export const CustomSandpack = () => (
  <SandpackProvider template="react">
    <CustomAceEditor />
    <SandpackPreview showRefreshButton={false} showOpenInCodeSandbox={false} />
  </SandpackProvider>
);
```

and here is my CustomAceEditor

```
import React from "react";
import axios from "axios";
import AceEditor from "react-ace";
import { useActiveCode } from "@codesandbox/sandpack-react";

import "ace-builds/src-noconflict/mode-javascript";
import "ace-builds/src-noconflict/theme-textmate";

export const CustomAceEditor = () => {
  const { code, updateCode } = useActiveCode();

  const handleSaveCode = async () => {
    try {
      await axios.post("http://localhost:3005/api/code", { code });
      alert("Code snippet saved successfully");
    } catch (error) {
      console.error("Error:", error);
      alert("An error occurred while saving the code snippet");
    }
    console.log("Code :", code);
  };

  return (
    <AceEditor
      mode="javascript"
      defaultValue={code}
      onChange={updateCode}
      fontSize={14}
      height="300px"
      width="100%"
      setOptions={{ useWorker: false }}
    />
    Save Code
  );
};
```